# Callback from C++ to C# inside another C++ callback function

Tags: c#, c++, callback

To callback from C++ to C#, we can do it like so:

C++:

```
void DoWork(ProgressCallback progressCallback)
{
   progressCallback(0);
}
```

C#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate void ProgressCallback(int value);

static void main() {
    ProgressCallback callback =
        (value) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Progress = {0}", value);
        };

    DoWork(callback);
}
```

The above implementation only works by passing the callback as a function parameter. But I want to be able to callback the function inside another callback function in C++. For example, if you have an event that gives you the time through a callback function called `OnTimeUpdated()`, I want to send this updated time information by calling the "C++ to C#" callback function INSIDE `OnTimeUpdated()` so that the C# side can have access to the time info. The issue is that if `OnTimeUpdated()` was an API callback function(not custom), then I wouldn't be able to pass in my callback function as a parameter. How do we deal with these cases? Any suggestions are appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually using c++cli? If so tag your question accordingly please.

Comment: I am not using any c++/cli. C++ code is accessed through DLLImport.

Comment: When I understand right, you are looking for a way to call the callback from "the other side" as your code describes. I think it is possible with c++/CLR only.

Comment: I think this is possible only via C++/ CLR or COM.

Comment: The code above makes the callback from "the other side" possible, without c++/CLR. My question is: given a pre-existing callback function, is there a way I can call my custom callback function INSIDE this pre-existing one - so that the Windows API callbacks can directly trasnfer to the C# side.